# How do I store product images in a separate table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to store multiple images in the database . I have products table , images table
in images table i have foreign key named "product_id"
i have stored product data successfully without images
how can i store images with product_id at same time storing this product

Here are the codes

Controller

```
 public function Store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $formInput=$request->all();
            product::create(array_merge($formInput,
            [
            'name' => $request->name,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'status' => $request->status,
            'category_id'  => $request->category_id,
            ],
    ));
            toastr()->success('Data Has been saved successfully ' , 'SUCCESS ');
            return redirect()->back();

        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            toastr()->success('An error has occurred ' , 'ERROR');
            return redirect()->back()->withInput();
            //return $ex ;
        }
    }
```

Product Model

```
    public function images(){
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class);    
    }
```

Image Model

```
    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
```

blade " single POST "

```
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple class="custom-file-input">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
i added this code on store function and is work fine with me

```
     $formInput=$request->all();
            $images=array();   
            
           
                $product = new Product();
                $product -> title = $request->title;
                $product -> description = $request->description;
                $product -> price = $request->price;
                $product -> status = $request->status;
                $product -> category_id =  $request->category_id;
                $product -> save();
            
            if($files=$request->file('images')){
                foreach($files as $file){
                    $name=$file->hashName();
                    $file->move('images',$name);
                    $images[]=$name;
                    Image::create(array_merge($formInput,
                    [
                        'product_id' => $product -> id,
                        'url' => ($name),
                        ],
                    ));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please update your question with how your data is getting passed from ui - is it single POST or AJAX or multiple AJAX

Comment: You can use InsertGetId() method to return product ID after saving the product. With this ID  you can save the data in images table.

Comment: `$product->images()->saveMany(ImageObject);` Try this.